# Recommended library for text extraction from news articles?

Tags: library, java, rss, feed-reader

I was tasked to make an RSS news aggregator for my GUIs University course. I'm already familiar with StAX and already managed to succesfully parse RSS feeds. What I want to do now is extract the important stuff from the news article (i.e. only the actual text of the article without title, banners etc.), so that I can store it in a String or something akin to that.

I've tried both BoilerPipe and Goose, both work fairly well, but both have pretty major issues, due to unmaintained status most likely. For example, Goose doesn't parse paragraphs that it thinks are "too short" but actually they're part of the article. BoilerPipe's ArticleExtractor (and LargestContentExtractor too) doesn't cut paragraphs but parses useless stuff, things such as "tweet us" or tags that are up in the page.

Does anybody know of more up-to-date libraries that do this and perform at least as well as Goose/BoilerPipe? I've heard things about Crux or Gander but I don't know if it suits my situation. Plus I don't know how to use them since documentation for those libs is very scarce, especially when it comes to Java use.